# How to fix "Deprecated configuration in workspace settings"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, liquid

In VS Code, when I'm in a file with Language Mode set to "Liquid" I see an alert in the
status bar.

The alert message says "Deprecated configuration in workspace settings. You are using v3.2.2 of the Liquid extension with old configurations that are no longer supported. You need to fix and align with the new configuration."

[image]

I can't figure out what I need to do to get rid of this alert.

When I go to Workspace Settings, I can see lots of settings but there's nothing flagged as needing attention.

And if I open the Workspace Settings JSON, it's just an empty pair of braces.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: If you click on the liquid extension in the Extension view and then click on the `Featured Contributions` in the extension's editor page it should list its settings.  You can make sure you are using those instead of something else.  In your `settings.json` deprecated settings may be indicated by a dimmed setting - but only if the extension's author has marked it as deprecated in its package.json.

Comment: Under `Featured Contributions` I just see all the same settings as under `CTRL+SHIFT+P > Workspace Settings`. I don't seem to have a `settings.json` anywhere - a new `.vscode` folder containing an empty file is generated in the current directory when I select `Workspace Settings JSON`.

Comment: What `liquid` extension(s) are you using?

Comment: This one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sissel.shopify-liquid

Comment: I've found if I edit a setting, so that it's added to `settings.json`, then the alert disappears - even if it has the same value as the default setting before I edited it. If I then `reset` the setting, the alert comes back. It's a bit annoying because I don't want to create pointless `settings.json` files all over the place